# Imputation by Class Average

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, imputation

I have a dataset with several variables that have a lot of missing data. I want to do an imputation by class considering a variable that has 3 categories as its level. I would like to be able to make a code that does this imputation for all variables automatically without having to do it by hand one by one.

```
medie_per_classe <- aggregate(. ~ Company_category, data = df, 
    FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I tried with this code, but i obtain only missing value- The code does not compute the mean

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It is not recommended to impute with mean. Consult your local statistician for advice.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, this will fill in all `NA`s with the mean grouped by `Company_category`, for all numeric columns in `your_data`

```
library(dplyr)

your_data |>
  mutate(across(
      where(is.numeric),
      \(x) coalesce(x, mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    ),
    .by = Company_category
  )
```

Comment: Sorry I am using r studio. I do not think that your code is in r studio

Comment: @SimoneCarminati RStudio isn't a language. It's a program for editing code, most commonly used with R. This is R code, using the extremely popular `dplyr` package. You may also not be familiar with the base R `|>` pipe operator, but it was introduced in R 4.1.0 over 2 years ago. This code will work in R whether you use RStudio, the R Gui, R through the command line, or any other way of using R. You just need the `dplyr` package installed, run `install.package("dplyr")` if you need to do that.

Comment: (And, if for some reason you are using a version of R that is more than 2 years old, you can replace `|>` with `%>%` and it will work with older versions.)

Comment: tentativo1 = df[,-3] %>%
+   mutate(across(
+     where(is.numeric),
+     \(x) coalesce(x, mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
+     .by = Company_category
+   ))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `Incorporation_date`.
Caused by error in `fn()`:
! argomento non utilizzato (.by = c("Medium sized company", "Medium sized company", "Small company", "Large company", "Small company", "Small company",  , 
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.ù

Comment: Ah, I misplaced a parenthesis. Typos are common when there is no sample data to test on. Let me edit.

Comment: Okay, edits made, try again. If you continue to run into problems, please make your question reproducible by sharing a little bit of sample data in your question.